# Incorrect Input String error when retrieving data from listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I keep getting an error of "Input String was not in a correct format" when trying to run this code.

The outcome is to retrieve data from one listbox to another, transferring only certain sections of the data.

```
Private Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
    'checks there is raw data loaded 
    If RawDataListBox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Data Has Been Loaded")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Splits the raw data into the structure
    Try
        Dim counterInteger As Integer = 12
        Dim FinalDataStructure(RawDataListBox.Items.Count) As FinalData
        Dim CleanDataString As String

        While counterInteger < RawDataListBox.Items.Count
            'reads one row into a string
            Dim FinalDataLineString As String = RawDataListBox.Items(counterInteger).ToString
            'Splits string by comma
            Dim FinalDataArrayString As String() = FinalDataLineString.Split(","c)
            FinalDataLineString.Replace("""", " ")

            With FinalDataStructure(counterInteger)
                .LocationNameString = FinalDataArrayString(0)
                .TypeString = FinalDataArrayString(1)
                .StateString = FinalDataArrayString(2)
                .FemalesInteger = Integer.Parse(FinalDataArrayString(3))
                .MalesInteger = Integer.Parse(FinalDataArrayString(4))
                'calculate the percentages and totals
                .TotalInteger = .FemalesInteger + .MalesInteger
                .PercentageFemaleInteger = .FemalesInteger + .TotalInteger
                .PercentageMaleInteger = .MalesInteger + .TotalInteger


            End With
            CleanDataString = "Location" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).LocationNameString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Type" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).TypeString + ","
            CleanDataString += "State" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).StateString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Females" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).FemalesInteger.ToString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Males" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).MalesInteger.ToString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Female Percentage" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).PercentageFemaleInteger.ToString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Male Percentage" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).PercentageMaleInteger.ToString + ","
            CleanDataString += "Total Population" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).TotalInteger.ToString + ","
            'Add to list box
            FinalDataListBox.Items.Add(CleanDataString)

            counterInteger += 1
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [MCVE]. As it stands this is just a debugging question which would be difficult to provide help on. Please also see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: A little tip that works for me .. comment out the  the try..catch..messagebox..end try code and run it to show exactly where the error occurred. Examine the string values at that line by hovering your mouse over the variables.

Comment: Instead of using + to concatenate your strings, you should use & - like this for your first line `CleanDataString = "Location" & FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).LocationNameString & ","` and like this `CleanDataString = CleanDatatring & "Type" & FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).TypeString & ","` for your subsequent lines

Comment: @DavidWilson, Thanks for your assistance, i fixed the issue. I was reading a line of data that related to something else and it was throwing it out.